# Что означает "сильность" в утверждение "Инвариант конструкции должен быть достаточно силен"?

Tags: математика, логика

Читая книгу "Почувствуй класс" Бертрана Мэйера, вижу слова:

> Заметьте: в общем случае нужно крайне тщательно проектировать инвариант, чтобы он позволял применить стратегию последовательной аппроксимации.
>
> - INV должен быть достаточно слабым, чтобы его можно было применить к некоторому начальному подмножеству, обычно содержащему совсем немного элементов из всего
>   множества.
> - Он достаточно силен, чтобы из него следовала цель Post, когда он выполняется на всем множестве.
> - Он достаточно гибкий, чтобы позволять расширять множество, сохраняя его истинность.

Как понимать "сильнее"?

Comment: Должен быть слабым, а силен он **будет** только тогда, когда выполняется на всем множестве.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, давайте рассмотрим на примере.

Вот классический алгоритм подсчёта [НОД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C):

```
if (m < 0) m = -m;
if (n < 0) n = -n;
while (m != 0 && n != 0)
{
    if (m > n)
        m -= n;
    else
        n -= m;
}
gcd = m + n;
```

Давайте подумаем, что у нас инвариант шага.

С одной стороны, очевидно, что в силу проверки *m* и *n* всегда положительны или 0. Это — инвариант: в начале он выполняется, а на каждом шаге у нас всегда уменьшаемое не меньше вычитаемого, так что после шага цикла инвариант всё ещё выполняется.

Но это — **слабый** инвариант, потому что из него не получится нужное постусловие: мы-то хотим доказать, что *gcd* содержит наибольший общий делитель! А из нашего инварианта это не следует.

Поэтому надо искать более **сильное** условие. Оно будет такое: *m* и *n* всегда положительны (или 0), и НОД(*m*, *n*) не меняется!

Первая часть условия нами уже доказана (она совпадает с прежним, слабым инвариантом). Вторая тоже легко следует из того, что НОД(*m*, *n*) = НОД(*m* − *n*, *n*). Таким образом, мы видим, что *если* цикл заканчивается, то в *gcd* будет ненулевое число из *m*, *n*, которое равно искомому НОД (т. к. НОД(*m*, 0) = *m*, НОД(0, *n*) = *n*).

(Стоит ещё добавить, что алгоритм гарантировано заканчивается, так как на каждом шаге наибольшее из *m*, *n* уменьшается хотя бы на 1, но в силу инварианта *m* и *n* не могут быть отрицательными, поэтому алгоритм не может продолжаться более чем (*m* + *n*) итераций. Вот и первое условие инварианта пригодилось!)

Comment: @VladD, просто круто!

Вы, случайно, не анализ алгоритмов где-нибудь преподаете?

Comment: 2VladD : ОК. Ваши слова : "более сильное условие". Что означает "сильное" ? Можно ли применять "сильность" в отношении двух условий, к примеру "условие1 сильнее условия2"?

Comment: @avp: Нет, но я когда-то занимался олимпиадной математикой, там приходилось доказывать справедливость алгоритмов. Спасибо!

Comment: @sys_dev: Условие #1 сильнее условия #2, если из него _следует_ условие #2. То есть как бы оно больше говорит о состоянии дел, даёт больше информации.

Comment: @VladD: Я бы к Вам в ученики пошел, пусть мне разрешат! ;)

Comment: @sys_dev: У многих на этом сайте есть чему поучиться. Спрашивайте!